# How to write unit test cases for custom sort pipe in angular 4?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { Opportunity } from "../models/Opportunity";

@Pipe({
    name: "orderBy",
    pure: false
})

export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
    /**
     * Method to sort data and return sorted data
     * 
     * @param records 
     * @param args 
     */
    transform(records: Array<any>, args?: any): any {
        return records.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a[args.property] < b[args.property]) {
                return -1 * args.order;
            }
            else if (a[args.property] > b[args.property]) {
                return 1 * args.order;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In my project where i have to implement sort for multiple columns so i want to write unit test cases for the above sort custom pipe in angular 4 version ?

Comment: What unit tests have you written so far? Is there a specific problem with them? Also note https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: i have any object of records eg: [{'name':'bharat', 'age':30},{'name':'apple', 'age':32}] and args = {'property':'name', order: 1 } and pipe is defined as an instance for OrderPipe a test case is like expect(pipe.transform(data, args)).toEqual(1);  and the error is expected 0 to equal 1

Comment: Why would you expect the result to be 1? And how could it be 0? Isn't the pipe supposed to return a sorted array? Maybe start by reading https://angular.io/guide/testing#pipe-testing

Comment: well in the args object i have defined order as '1'  so either the control goes to if case or else if case but the control always goes to else case. I did not understand where it went wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I created an object of my pipe in my describe:

```js
const pipe = new OrderByPipe()
```

And, then do the usual test cases like : `expect(pipe.transform([5,1,6,7]).toEqual([1,5,6,7])`, testing corner cases etc.